# How do i split this list into pairs or single elements. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Tags: python, list

In python I have a list of names, however some have a second name and some do not, how would I split the list into names with surnames and names without?

I don't really know how to explain it so please look at the code and see if you can understand (sorry if I have worded it really badly in the title)

See code below :D

```
names = ("Donald Trump James Barack Obama Sammy John Harry Potter")
# the names with surnames are the famous ones
# names without are regular names

list = names.split()
# I want to separate them into a list of separate names so I use split()
# but now surnames like "Trump" are counted as a name

print("Names are:",list)
```

This outputs
`['Donald', 'Trump', 'James', 'Barack', 'Obama', 'Sammy', 'John', 'Harry', 'Potter']`
I would like it to output something like `['Donald Trump', 'James', 'Barack Obama', 'Sammy', 'John', 'Harry Potter']`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have a database of "famous names" that can help guide the split? If not, this problem is not well defined

Comment: You need to have a database/set of famous names like is mentioned. Python, and any language really, is not going to have a built in split function that knows to distinguish between `James`, `James Barack`, and `Barack Obama`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, you need a list of famous names.

```
# complete list of famous people
US_PRESIDENTS = (('Donald', 'Trump'), ('Barack', 'Obama'), ('Harry', 'Potter'))

def splitfamous(namestring):
    words = namestring.split()
    # create all tuples of 2 adjacent words and compare them to US_PRESIDENTS
    for i, name in enumerate(zip(words, words[1:])):
        if name in US_PRESIDENTS:
            words[i] = ' '.join(name)
            words[i+1] = None      
    # remove empty fields and return the result
    return list(filter(None, words))

names = "Donald Trump James Barack Obama Sammy John Harry Potter"
print(splitfamous(names))
```

The resulting list:

```
['Donald Trump', 'James', 'Barack Obama', 'Sammy', 'John', 'Harry Potter']
```